# WinRT Grid, Remove UIElement placed with Grid.SetRow(element, rowIndex)

Tags: c#, .net, grid, windows-runtime, uielement

Like the title says. **I have a grid into which i place several elements** via the `Grid.SetRow()` method:

```
Grid.SetRow(myElement, 0);
```

Later on **I want to remove these items** but I have no idea how.

Just dropping the reference to the ui element doesnt seem to do the trick.

*Any ideas?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it using the `Children` collection in the grid variable:

```
// get grid instance
Grid grid = GetGrid();
// Remove element
grid.Children.Remove(myElement);
```

Comment: turns out i`m stupid, i added my children to the related grid of course! Thx! :-)